# NULL returned for NSDateFormatter in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Here's the code in question:

```
// configure created_at date for display
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSLog(@"formattedDate=%@",dateFormatter.dateFormat);
NSLog(@"created_at=%@",notice.created_at);
NSString *createdDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:notice.created_at];
NSLog(@"createdDateStr=%@",createdDateStr);
self.labelCreated.text=createdDateStr;
```

And here's what's coming out per NSLog:

```
2014-06-29 12:06:48.945 [3589:60b] formattedDate=MMM d, y
2014-06-29 12:06:48.947 [3589:60b] created_at=2013-02-22T08:49:52Z
2014-06-29 12:06:48.948 [3589:60b] createdDateStr=(null)
```

This looks a lot more complicated that it needs to be, but I was following examples from the Mac Developers Library (iOS 7.x, Xcode 5.x)  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `notice.created_at` is already an `NSString`, not an `NSDate`. There is nothing to convert unless you wish to change the format of the string.

Comment: Actually, it's an NSDate: `@property (readonly) NSDate   *created_at;`

Comment: Not according to the log output.

Comment: rmaddy - not sure to what you're referring - in the "code in question" section above, you'll see the line, `NSString *createdDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:notice.created_at];` - it takes `notice.created_at` as an NSDate parameter for the conversion of `stringFromDate`.  I don't think this is where the problem is...

Comment: I'm talking about the 2nd `NSLog` statement. It is logging an `NSString`, not an `NSDate`. This means you are passing an `NSString` to the `stringFromDate:` method. This is why you get a `nil` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your created_at date format is different. So first you need to set the dateformat accordingly as created_at dateformat like that below:-

```
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

Comment: Hussain Shabbir - this was tricky to figure out, but your suggestion led me to the correct solution.  I have a legitimate NSDate, but with a Time Zone suffix.  Had to create an input formatter, pass it my NSDate, as a formatted string, and return a "friendly" NSDate.  Then, had to create a corresponding output formatter and return the desired string. Now works like this: (in next comment :-)

Comment: NSDateFormatter *inFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [inFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
    NSDate *inDate = [inFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",document.created_at]];
    NSDateFormatter *outFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    NSString *outDate = [outFormatter stringFromDate:inDate];
    self.labelCreated.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",outDate];

Answer (score 1):

Please consider, if you are converting date format from string, you should write the format exactly like in your string with spaces etc. Other ways date format will return null